# Running Cron Job's for data generation from within MongoDB itself

Tags: c#, mongodb, cron, scheduled-tasks, data-generation

Here is the information about my development environment:

-MongoDB 3.0.0

-MongoDB C# Driver Version 1.7.0.4714

-Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013

-.NET Framework 4.0

In the MongoDB Database, there is a Users Collection, and a DiaryEntries would be a collection.

Let's say that we have to generate some Daily Diary Entries for our Users if the Users haven't logged on to create it themselves.

We could create a Windows task scheduler to run a cron job C# program to create the Diary Entry for each of the users of our application that don't have it for the current day.

However, as time goes by, there will be a huge number of Users in the application, and it seems that a cron job C# program running everyday by first checking if each of the Users have a Daily Diary Entry, and then only creating a Daily Diary Entry if the User does Not have it for that day.

I was wondering if there was a way of running Cron Job's for data generation from within MongoDB itself to do the aforementioned task.  If yes, would possible be better performance than doing the task from C#?  If it is better performance than doing it from C# then please tell me how it can be implemented from within MongoDB itself?

Answer (score 1):

No, MongoDB does not have a task scheduler.

In my experience cron jobs perform very nicely. If you do a lot of writes then using the bulk API provides a big improvement.

You could do your job in JavaScript and then run it using the Mongo shell, but I haven't experienced performance benefits going down this way. Only real benefit is that writing a shell script is sometimes easier than other languages.

Comment: Sorry, could you please provide me more information on the batch API that you mentioned?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the bulk API.

Comment: Do you mean MongoDb's Bulk API?